# Facebook messenger live bot unable to receive public messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My bot is live however still only users whom are added as tester/developer role are only able to access the bot. Why is general public unable to access the bot?

[image: Facebook messenger live bot]

[image: Approved items]

I cannot see a problem in the messaging pipeline - since people with tester/developer roles are able to send/receive messages...

[I don't see `pages_messaging` anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763799/2404470)

[image: no pages_messaging]

What else is required to receive messages from general public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit your facebook app for review. For sending and receiving messages to the users your apps needs pages_messaging permission . You can find it in the messenger product tab.